# FIlementphp Admin protect issue

Tags: laravel, middleware, filamentphp

I use `filamentphp` admin panel on laravel

I create a middleware `VerifyIsAdmin` which has the following code:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
        if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->is_admin) {
            return $next($request);
        }else{
            return abort(403, 'You are not authorized to access this page.');
        }
    }
```

and use this `middleware` on admin panel provider

```
->middleware([
                EncryptCookies::class,
                AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
                StartSession::class,
                AuthenticateSession::class,
                ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
                VerifyCsrfToken::class,
                SubstituteBindings::class,
                DisableBladeIconComponents::class,
                DispatchServingFilamentEvent::class,
                VerifyIsAdmin::class
            ])
```

I tried to access `admin/login` route without login and got the following error

> You are not authorized to access this page.

I expected that accessing the admin/login route would be allowed without authentication, but other admin routes would require authentication and admin status verification.

How do I resolve the issue?

Comment: So you want only Admin role of the users table to allow acessing the filament ?